# Apple TV from Apple One and Apple TV free trial on new devices conflict

Tags: iphone, appletv

I bought a new iPhone for a family member and added them to family sharing. Everything works (Apple Music, Apple Arcade, etc) but not Apple TV.

This is because there's a conflict between the Apple One subscription and the Apple TV "get one year for free" offer for newly purchased Apple devices.

When the Apple TV app is opened, it offers 1 year for free (even though the subscription from Apple One is active). But when you click to accept the free year of Apple TV, it says that you already have Apple TV through Apple One in a pop-up window. You click "ok", and then it keeps telling you that you can get 1 year of Apple TV for free and won't let you play anything... And then it's a vicious cycle, you click to Accept one year for free, and it tells you that you already have it through Apple One again.

How do you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a weird bug from Apple. I found a workaround to get it to work. Steps:

1. Remove the family member from Apple One.
2. Go to Apple TV on their phone, now it will let you accept the free year of Apple TV and won't tell you that you already have it through Apple One. Click to accept one year of Apple TV.
3. Now add the family member to family sharing again. And they will have everything working.
4. Go to Settings -> Click on the rectangle with your name at the very top -> Subscriptions -> Apple TV (the one that you subscribed to for 1 year free) and cancel it.

This made everything work for me.